# 2D Array's last element is null. ( Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array

```
for (int i = 0; i < getFileLines() ; i++) {
    readLineString = bf4.readLine();
    for (int j = 0; j < secondLineArray.length ; j++) {
        readLineArray = readLineString.split(";");
        readLineArray2D[i][j] = readLineArray[j];
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(readLineArray2D).replace("], ","]\n"));
```

Here I initialise the arrays

```
secondLineString = bf3.readLine();
secondLineArray = secondLineString.split(";");
readLineArray = readLineString.split(";");
readLineArray2D[i][j] = readLineArray[j];
```

with the `system.out.println()` method, the last element of my file is "null". The whole row is marked as null. It seems, that the loop is adding one extra row to the array. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: i added something.

Comment: Ok to change my question: Have you checked if `secondLineArray.length == readLineArray.length`?

Comment: Where do you iterate over second line? Or you don't? Add some more code please in order to find the problem

Comment: I am not sure what the exercise is. Do you know how an 2D array work? What are example values of what you read and want to put into the array? What are you expecting the array to contain, versus what it actually contains?